jQuery submit button reloads the page even with preventDefault() in WordPress
I have some jQuery that I plug some numbers in via some text fields then it should print out the results, this works fine on my local machine.
However, when I add to my WordPress environment, the submit button just refreshes the page.
Any idea why this is?


jQuery("#roi").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.cost_by_industry = parseInt($("#cost_by_ind").val());
  window.cost_by_employee_count = parseInt($("#cost_by_employee_c").val());
  window.no_empoyees = parseInt($("#no_emp").val());
  window.month_invest = parseInt($("#month_inv").val());
  window.expected_a_grow = 0.05;
  window.aas = 120000;
  window.fpr = 0.75;
  window.avr = 0.75;

  //managed risk year 1
  var roiCalc = function () {
    return ((0.3 * (cost_by_industry + cost_by_employee_count)) / 2) * 0.2;
  };
  var result = roiCalc();
  const formattedPrice1 = result.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //managed risk year 2
  var roiCalc2 = function () {
    return result * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var result2 = roiCalc2();
  const formattedPrice2 = result2.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //managed risk year 3
  var roiCalc3 = function () {
    return result2 * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var result3 = roiCalc3();
  const formattedPrice3 = result3.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //managed risk total
  var roiCalcfinal = function () {
    return result + result2 + result3;
  };
  var results_total = roiCalcfinal();
  const formattedPrice_total_mr = results_total.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //Empower Analysts year 1
  var roiCalc_emp_1 = function () {
    return (no_empoyees / 2000) * aas;
  };
  var ea_result = roiCalc_emp_1();
  const formattedPrice_ea_1 = ea_result.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //Empower Analysts year 2
  var roiCalc_emp_2 = function () {
    return ea_result * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var ea_result2 = roiCalc_emp_2();
  const formattedPrice_ea_2 = ea_result2.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //Empower Analysts year 3
  var roiCalc_emp_3 = function () {
    return ea_result2 * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var ea_result3 = roiCalc_emp_3();
  const formattedPrice_ea_3 = ea_result3.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  ///Empower Analysts total
  var roiCalc_emp_final = function () {
    return ea_result + ea_result2 + ea_result3;
  };
  var emp_results_total = roiCalc_emp_final();
  const formattedPrice_total_ea = emp_results_total.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //TP year 1
  var tp1 = function () {
    return month_invest * (1 - fpr) * 3 * 2 * (aas / 2080) * 12;
  };
  var tp1_results = tp1();

  //FP year 1
  var fp1 = function () {
    return month_invest * fpr * 3 * 1 * (aas / 2080) * 12;
  };
  var fp1_results = fp1();

  //TP year 2
  var tp2 = function () {
    return month_invest * (1 - avr) * (1 - fpr) * 3 * 1 * (aas / 2080) * 12;
  };
  var tp2_results = tp2();

  //fp year 2
  var fp2 = function () {
    return month_invest * (1 - avr) * fpr * 3 * 0.5 * (aas / 2080) * 12;
  };
  var fp2_results = fp2();

  //reduce aleart vol year 1
  var rav1 = function () {
    return tp2_results + fp2_results + tp1_results + fp1_results;
  };
  var rav_results_1 = rav1();
  const formattedPrice_year_rav_1 = rav_results_1.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //reduce aleart vol year 2
  var rav2 = function () {
    return rav_results_1 * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var rav_results_2 = rav2();
  const formattedPrice_year_rav_2 = rav_results_2.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //reduce aleart vol year 3
  var rav3 = function () {
    return rav_results_2 * (1 + expected_a_grow);
  };
  var rav_results_3 = rav3();
  const formattedPrice_year_rav_3 = rav_results_3.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  //reduce aleart vol total
  var rav_total = function () {
    return rav_results_1 + rav_results_2 + rav_results_3;
  };
  var rav_results = rav_total();
  const formattedPrice_total_rav = rav_results.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  });

  $("#output").show();
  $(".manage_risk_1").text(formattedPrice1);
  $(".manage_risk_2").text(formattedPrice2);
  $(".manage_risk_3").text(formattedPrice3);
  $(".results_total").text(formattedPrice_total_mr);
  $(".emp_results_1").text(formattedPrice_ea_1);
  $(".emp_results_2").text(formattedPrice_ea_2);
  $(".emp_results_3").text(formattedPrice_ea_3);
  $(".emp_results_total").text(formattedPrice_total_ea);
  // $(".tp1_results").text(tp1_results);
  // $(".tp2_results").text(tp2_results);
  // $(".fp1_results").text(fp1_results);
  // $(".fp2_results").text(fp2_results);
  $(".rav_results_1").text(formattedPrice_year_rav_1);
  $(".rav_results_2").text(formattedPrice_year_rav_2);
  $(".rav_results_3").text(formattedPrice_year_rav_3);
  $(".rav_results_total").text(formattedPrice_total_rav);
});
#output {
  display: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.help-inline {
  display: none;
}
.result {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.roi-success {
  background: #269526;
  color: white;
}
.roi-danger {
  background: #d74e26;
  color: white;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <p class="lead">copy copy copy </p>
      <form id="roi">
        <b>test</b>
        <select id="cost_by_ind">
          <option value="10930000">Healthcare</option>
          <option value="5900000">Financial</option>
          <option value="4820000">Pharmaceuticals</option>
          <option value="4780000">Energy</option>
        </select>
        <b>Cost by employe count</b>
        <select id="cost_by_employee_c">
          <option value="3310000">0 - 499</option>
          <option value="3290000">500 - 1000-</option>
          <option value="4870000">1001 - 5000</option>
          <option value="4330000">5001 - 10000</option>
          <option value="5460000">10001 - 25000</option>
          <option value="5420000">25001 - 100000</option>
        </select>

        <div class="control-group">
          <b>No Employees</b>
          <input id="no_emp" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Number of Employees">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <b>Monthly </b>
          <input id="month_inv" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Investigations">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate ROI</button>
      </form>
      <!--show output here-->
      <div class="well" id="output">

        <p> year 1 = <span class="manage_risk_1"></span></p>
        <p> year 2 = <span class="manage_risk_2"></span></p>
        <p> year 3 = <span class="manage_risk_3"></span></p>
        <strong>Total k = <span class="results_total"></span></strong>

        <p>Es year 1 = <span class="emp_results_1"></span></p>

        <p>year 2 = <span class="emp_results_2"></span></p>

        <p>year 3 = <span class="emp_results_3"></span></p>

        <strong>Total   = <span class="emp_results_total"></span></strong>

        <!--         <p>TP1 <span class="tp1_results"></span></p>

        <p>TP2 <span class="tp2_results"></span></p>

        <p>FP1 <span class="fp1_results"></span></p>

        <p>FP2 <span class="fp2_results"></span></p> -->

        <p> year 1 = <span class="rav_results_1"></span></p>

        <p> year 2 = <span class="rav_results_2"></span></p>

        <p> year 3 = <span class="rav_results_3"></span></p>

        <strong>Total  = <span class="rav_results_total"></span></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




How are you adding it to the WordPress? Have you created a custom plugin or just paste that code in the editor?

When you debug, did jQuery("#roi") find the element and attach the submit handler?  Is the handler invoked when the form is submitted?  What happens when stepping through that handler with the browser's debugger?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

As this is an online calculator powered by JavaScript on client side, you don't need really the form to submit data via Post or Get methods.
So in your case, you can replace your submit button with a normal button like (added "calculate-roi" to the class attribute values):
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block calculate-roi">Calculate ROI</button>

Then I have changed your JavaScript code to handle that, optimizing and compacting your code:
jQuery(function($){
    // Function that formats a raw price amount
    function formatPrice( rawPrice ) {
        return rawPrice.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "USD"
        });
    }

    $('form#roi').on('click', '.calculate-roi', function() {
        const cost_by_industry = parseInt($("#cost_by_ind").val()),
            cost_by_employee_count = parseInt($("#cost_by_employee_c").val()),
            no_empoyees = parseInt($("#no_emp").val()),
            month_invest = parseInt($("#month_inv").val()),
            expected_a_grow = 0.05,
            aas = 120000,
            fpr = 0.75,
            avr = 0.75,
            //managed risk year 1
            mr_result1 = ((0.3 * (cost_by_industry + cost_by_employee_count)) / 2) * 0.2,
            //managed risk year 2
            mr_result2 = mr_result1 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //managed risk year 3
            mr_result3 = mr_result2 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //managed risk total
            mr_results_total = mr_result1 + mr_result2 + mr_result3,
            //Empower Analysts year 1
            ea_result1 = (no_empoyees / 2000) * aas,
            //Empower Analysts year 2
            ea_result2 = ea_result1 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //Empower Analysts year 3
            ea_result3 = ea_result2 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //Empower Analysts total
            ea_results_total = ea_result1 + ea_result2 + ea_result3,
            //TP year 1
            tp1_results = month_invest * (1 - fpr) * 3 * 2 * (aas / 2080) * 12,
            //fp year 1
            fp1_results = month_invest * fpr * 3 * 1 * (aas / 2080) * 12,
            //TP year 2
            tp2_results = month_invest * (1 - avr) * (1 - fpr) * 3 * 1 * (aas / 2080) * 12,
            //fp year 2
            fp2_results = month_invest * (1 - avr) * fpr * 3 * 0.5 * (aas / 2080) * 12,
            //reduce aleart vol year 1
            rav_results_1 = tp2_results + fp2_results + tp1_results + fp1_results,
            //reduce aleart vol year 2
            rav_results_2 = rav_results_1 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //reduce aleart vol year 3
            rav_results_3 = rav_results_2 * (1 + expected_a_grow),
            //reduce aleart vol total
            rav_results_total = rav_results_1 + rav_results_2 + rav_results_3;

        $("#output").show();
        $(".manage_risk_1").text(formatPrice(mr_result1));
        $(".manage_risk_2").text(formatPrice(mr_result2));
        $(".manage_risk_3").text(formatPrice(mr_result3));
        $(".results_total").text(formatPrice(mr_results_total));
        $(".emp_results_1").text(formatPrice(ea_result1));
        $(".emp_results_2").text(formatPrice(ea_result2));
        $(".emp_results_3").text(formatPrice(ea_result3));
        $(".emp_results_total").text(formatPrice(ea_results_total));
        // $(".tp1_results").text(tp1_results);
        // $(".tp2_results").text(tp2_results);
        // $(".fp1_results").text(fp1_results);
        // $(".fp2_results").text(fp2_results);
        $(".rav_results_1").text(formatPrice(rav_results_1));
        $(".rav_results_2").text(formatPrice(rav_results_2));
        $(".rav_results_3").text(formatPrice(rav_results_3));
        $(".rav_results_total").text(formatPrice(rav_results_total));
    });
});

Now your related page in WordPress will not be reloaded anymore.
